# Problem in installing npm install -g composer-cli in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric

Hi I am trying to install composer-cli using npm
but it is throwing error.
the log of the error is as below:

```
18988 error code ELIFECYCLE
18989 error errno 1
18990 error grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
18990 error Exit status 1
18991 error Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
18991 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
18992 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried every possible way to fix this issue. but couldn't find any solution.

Please let me know how to fix the issue.

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-34-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/dspl_user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/dspl_user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/dspl_user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dspl_user/.npm/_logs/2018-09-27T13_11_13_477Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

i resolved the same problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine by =>

Installing pre-requisites at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html

which says->

```
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

then

```
chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

and at last =>

```
./prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

then restart your terminal and try the installation =>

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
```

without su or sudo. I hope this helps :):)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same error as you. It's working for me now after switching to Node 8.9.0. It looks like you're using Node v10, which is not supported for hyperledger fabric.